# Удалить/восстановить блок в зависимости от разрешения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно удалить/восстановить блок кода силами javascript/jQuery?

Необходимо чтобы при разрешении больше `600px` блок удалялся, при разрешении меньше `600px`, блок восстанавливался. Блок нужно именно удалить, а не скрыть.
Думал, что в данном случае необходимо:

1. записать данный блок в переменную (с помощью `.html()`)
2. поставить условие:
   2.1 если разрешение экрана больше `600px`, блок убрать (через `.detach()`)
   2.2 если разрешение экрана меньше, вставить в контейнер ранее записанный в переменную блок (через `.append()`)

В итоге удалять блок получается, а вот вернуть его уже нет.
Набросал примерную конструкцию - [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/nthm9L4o/3/) на jsfiddle

```js
function mobileNav() {
  var $mobileWidth = $(window).width();
  var $hideBlock = $('#hide');
  var $contentWrap = $('wrapper');

  if ($mobileWidth >= 600) {
    $hideBlock.detach();
  } else {
    $contentWrap.append($hideBlock);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  mobileNav();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  mobileNav();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="hide">
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

После `$hideBlock.detach();` этого элемента больше нет в DOM-е страницы, последующие вызовы `$("#hide")` его не найдут. Используйте `$hideBlock.hide()`/`$hideBlock.show()` или сохраняйте ссылку на `$hideBlock`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $hideBlock = $('#hide');
  var $contentWrap = $('.wrapper');

  function mobileNav() {
    var $mobileWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($mobileWidth >= 600) {
      $hideBlock.detach();
    } else {
      $contentWrap.append($hideBlock);
    }
  }
  mobileNav();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    mobileNav();
  });
});
```

Comment: Так они просто устанавливают свойство display: none, а мне нужно чтоб именно в DOM его не было.   И на скок я понял .detach() все таки как то позволяет восстановить элемент, ток не разберусь как.   http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @TemTik Вы полностью прочитали ответ?

Comment: Понял) дошло) А сохранять ссылку это что такое?